# What is wrong with my linked list program? (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to insert an element at second last place of my linked list...Please help me out
I have created a function to enumerate the linked list with values 1,2,3...etc
Then I have a function to insert at second last, and then I have a function to display the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head=NULL;
void insert(int x){
 int i = 1;
 struct node *temp,*temp2=head;
 while(x>0){
     x--;
     temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     head->data=i++;
     head->next=temp;
     head=temp;
     }
     head->next=NULL;
head=temp2;
}

void insertSecondLast(int x){
struct node *prev,*insert,*temp=head;
insert = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
insert->data=x;
while(head->next!=NULL){
    prev = head;
    head=head->next;
    }
prev->next=insert;
insert->next=head;
head=temp;
}

void display(){
    printf("\n[");
    while(head->next!=NULL){
        printf("%d, ",head->data);
        head=head->next;
    }
    printf("NULL]");
}


int main(void) {

     insert(4);
     insertSecondLast(100);
     display();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. But look at your insert function. You are dereferencing head before ever setting it.

Comment: e.g. What is the address held by `head` the first time you encounter `head->data=i++;`?

Comment: Read absolutely [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also `display` functions should be `while(head) { printf("%d, ", head->data); head = head->next; }`

Comment: Thanks @David C. Rankin ... I allocated the memory now it runs.

Comment: Thanks @Barmak Shemirani... I know there are other issues... I will fix them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insert function, you are de-referencing the NULL pointer (head is set to NULL initially). The OS does not allow you to de-reference the NULL address, so you get a seg fault at run-time.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I allocated memory for head in the main function.  Now it runs. Thanks